# How to observe multiple Firebase entries in a loop and run completion block once every observe function has finished?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to create a feed that should include posts made by people a user follows, and I'm using following function to get posts for user feed:

```
func observePosts(for userID: String, completion: @escaping ([UserPost], String) -> Void) {
        
    let databaseKey = "Posts/\(userID)/"
    
    databaseRef.child(databaseKey).queryOrderedByKey().queryLimited(toLast: 12).observe(.value) { snapshot in
        
        var retrievedPosts = [UserPost]()
        var lastSeenPostKey = ""
        let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()
        
        for snapshotChild in snapshot.children.reversed() {
            
            guard let postSnapshot = snapshotChild as? DataSnapshot,
                  let postDictionary = postSnapshot.value as? [String: Any]
            else {
                print("Couldn't cast snapshot as DataSnapshot")
                return
            }
            dispatchGroup.enter()
            lastSeenPostKey = postSnapshot.key
            
            do {
                let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: postDictionary as Any)
                let decodedPost = try JSONDecoder().decode(UserPost.self, from: jsonData)
                
                UserService.shared.observeUser(for: decodedPost.userID) { postAuthor in
                    decodedPost.author = postAuthor
                    retrievedPosts.append(decodedPost)
                     dispatchGroup.leave()
                }
                
            } catch {
                print("Couldn't create UserPost from postDictionary")
            }
        }
        dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
            completion(retrievedPosts, lastSeenPostKey)
        }
    }
}
```

First step I'm getting user feed posts with .observe function and after that I'm iterating through every received post calling a `UserService.shared.observeUser` method that observes user data for every post to set post author's profile picture and username.

The problem with my method is that I'm using DispatchGroup's .enter and .leave methods to notify once every observe function got user data so that I could call completion block in which I'm reloading tableView.

Sure it works fine first time but since it's observe function it's called every time there's a change to user so once user updates his data (profile pic, usernama etc.) it crashes on `dispatchGroup.leave()` line since it's not balanced with `dispatchGroup.enter()`

What would be a correct approach to solve this issue?

I've been trying to solve this problem for 3 days searching all the internet, and only advice I found is to fetch it one time using `observeSingleValue()` instead of observing, but I really need to observe user profile data to keep profile pics and other necessary data up to date.